# Can I change the layouts randomly with ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

My problem is that I want to go from layout 1 to any other layout by pressing a `Button`.
For example:

From layout 1 with `setDisplayChild(R.id.layout3)` to go to layout 3 from a total of 4 layouts(Doesn't work).

I made a container.xml that includes all four layout, but I can't go for example from layout 2 to layout 4 directly without using `flipper.showNext()` or `flipper.showPrevious()` two times or things like this, the methods `showNext()` and `showPrevious()` are just to go forward or back and I need to go to any other layouts.

Is there a method for `ViewFlipper` to go from layout 1(or other layouts) to other layouts(that are not the neighbouring layouts) or the `ViewFlipper` knows just to go next, previous or the first layout(child)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a method on viewFlipper to go from layout1 (or other layots)
>   to other layouts(that are not the neighoubrs layouts) or the flipper
>   knows just to go next,previous or the first layout(child) ?

Yes, there is the method [`setDisplayedChild`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setDisplayedChild%28int%29) from the `ViewAnimator` class which is the parent of `ViewFlipper` which allows you to move the `ViewFlipper` to whatever child you want.

> For exemple: From layout1 with setDisplayChild(R.id.layout3) to go to
>   layout 3 from a total of 4 layouts. (Doesen't work)

The `setDisplayedChild` requires that you pass to it the **position** of the desired `View` in the `ViewFlipper` element and **not the id** of that layout like you use it. So if you want to jump to one of the children of `ViewFlipper` just use:

```
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2); // jumps to the third child
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2); // another call like the one below will not move the ViewFlipper as it is already at the third child
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1); // jumps to the second child
```

If you want to have the `ViewFlipper` move randomly through its children, then you could have:

```
Random mRandom = new Random();
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(mRandom.nextInt(4)); // 4 for 4 children
```

Comment: Thank you very much  , i had waited a little for my respons but the solution that i got it's briliant! Thank you very very much!